# Structure of {Null, Identity, Limit points, Adherent points, Isolated points}

Tags: general-topology

Let's denote (N,I,AP,LP,IP):=(Null, Identity, Adherent points, Limit points, Isolated points).
What is known what kind of structure/algebra it is with respect to composition as an multiplication operator it may be?

AP(AP(S))=AP(S)

AP(LP(S))=

AP(IP(S))=

LP(AP(S))=LP(S)

LP(LP(S))=LP(S)

LP(IP(S))=

IP(AP(S))=

IP(LP(S))=$\emptyset$

IP(IP(S))=

Comment: AP(LP(S)) = LP(S) because the set of limit points is closed (I'm assuming a $T_1$ space or better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a $T_1$ space the set of limit points $S'$ is itself closed (so equal to its adherence/closure) so AP(LP(S))=LP(S) in that case.

IP(LP(S)) = $\emptyset$ need not hold: let $S=\{0\} \cup \{\frac1n\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ (usual topology) then LP(S) = $\{0\}$ = IP(LP(S)) $\neq \emptyset$

LP(LP(S)) need not equal LP(S): take a convergent sequence (as the previous one) in $\Bbb R$, e.g.

LP(AP(S)) = LP(S) is OK (I think, not sure if it needs a separation axiom)..

So your "algebra" idea seems  doomed to me. Not enough structure.